# Mocking a singleton in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock

In Groovy / Spock I can mock a class by doing:

```
def theClass = Mock(TheClass.class)
```

and then wire that instance into the class under unit test. What about if I want to mock a class that has been annotated as a @Singleon

Comment: Why would you need to mock a singleton? I've never seen a good reason to do so.

Comment: I am unit testing a specific class. It calls an API from the the singleton which goes off and gets a bunch of data from parsing a bunch of files and return a List of objects.  I just want to stub out the the returned list of objects.

Comment: You accepted Leonard's answer. Why? It does not work. Can you please show how you did it? I was trying to replicate his solution, but it just does not work for code actually accessing `MySingleton.instance`. Wasn't that your use case? For that I need to use my helper class to explicitly change the singleton instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [global mocks](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#MockingAllInstancesOfAType)

```
def publisher = new Publisher()
publisher << new RealSubscriber() << new RealSubscriber()

def anySubscriber = GroovyMock(RealSubscriber, global: true)

when:
publisher.publish("message")

then:
2 * anySubscriber.receive("message")
```

Comment: I think this does not work because `RealSubscriber.instance` will be null. Furthermore, global mocks only work for Groovy classes. What if `Publisher` is a Java class?

Comment: The question had only the tags groovy and spock, so I assumed that the code in question is groovy code. If the target is used by java code it won't work.

Comment: Maybe you are missing my point. It does not work with 100% Groovy code either due to the `@Singleton` annotation in the to-be-mocked class. The referring class tries to access it via `MySingleton.instance` and fails because it does not get the global Groovy mock but the original object. So I think there is no easy way around my helper class.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little tool class you can use:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

class GroovySingletonTool<T> {
  private Class<T> clazz

  GroovySingletonTool(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz
  }

  void setSingleton(T instance) {
    // Make 'instance' field non-final
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("instance")
    field.modifiers &= ~Modifier.FINAL
    // Only works if singleton instance was unset before
    field.set(clazz.instance, instance)
  }

  void unsetSingleton() {
    setSingleton(null)
  }

  void reinitialiseSingleton() {
    // Unset singleton instance, otherwise subsequent constructor call will fail
    unsetSingleton()
    setSingleton(clazz.newInstance())
  }
}
```

Just call `setSingleton(Mock(TheClass))`. For more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604928/1082681), I do not want to repeat the whole sample code here.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions if there is anything you do not understand.